# False proof that a morphism of sheaves is an epimorphism if and only if it is pointwise epic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $C$ be a concrete category which is cocomplete. I tried to prove the different characterizations of monomorphisms of sheaves in the following way.

[image]

I think this proof is correct (please do tell me if there's anything wrong or anything that can be better explained). Nevertheless, it seems to me that the exact same proof would prove that $\varphi$ is an epimorphism if and only if $\varphi_U$ is an epimorphism for every open set $U\subset X$, which is false. Where my proof fails?

Comment: It seems to me that there is a little jump in the reasoning after the larger commutative diagram. In particular I think one has to use that the vertical arrows are also monomorphisms. For epimorphisms the diagram is a different one, so I dont see why this proof should carry over. My guess is that in this diagram one needs that the vertical arrows are epimorphisms which is in general false.

Comment: @BenediktK Since $\mathscr{H}$, $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ are sheaves, the vertical arrows are injections. (Note that I am working in a concrete category.) For epimorphisms we would have a similar diagram with double arrows on the right. However, I think that what we would need in this case indeed is that the vertical arrows be injections.

Comment: I have to admit that I am not very familar with the notion of a concrete category. So I am thinking about the category of Sets here. In the proof when we use the assumption $(b)$ we actually dont get that the morphisms between the products of stalks are the same, only their composition with the leftmost vertical arrow are. For epimorphisms, before we can actually invoke the assumption that all maps $\varphi_p$ are surjective,we need to know that the two horizontal compositions on the bottom are the same. To conclude this from the commutativity we need that the leftmost vertical is surjective.

Comment: I think we actually get that the morphisms between the products of stalks are the same since the morphisms between each of the factors are equal. Am I wrong?

Comment: The commutativity of the large diagram means that the two morphisms $\mathscr{H}(U)\rightarrow\prod \mathscr{H}_p\rightarrow\prod \mathscr{F}_p\rightarrow\prod \mathscr{G}_p$ are the same. Let $\pi_p :\mathscr{H}(U)\rightarrow\mathscr{H}_p$ be one of the components of the left arrow. Then this means that $\varphi_p\circ\psi_p\circ\pi_p=\varphi_p\circ\psi'_p\circ\pi_p$. From the fact that $\varphi_p$ is mono we only get $\psi_p\circ\pi_p=\psi'_p\circ\pi_p$, i.e the components are not the same, only if we precompose them with $\pi_p$.

Comment: Frankly, I begin to think that $\psi_p$ does not even make sense. (Not even in my proof about monomorphisms!) In our hypothesis, $\psi_U$ and $\psi_U'$ are just morphisms in $C$. They don't have to come from a morphism of sheaves. Maybe you have some idea about how this proof may still work...

Comment: You are right. That is a problem indeed.

Comment: This may help in the case where $C$ is the category of Sets: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3574832/672472

Comment: @BenediktK This is about the category of presheaves. A mono/epimorphism in the category of presheaves is not the same as in the category of sheaves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115160/discussion-between-benediktk-and-gabriel).

Comment: If you want to prove that $\varphi_U$ is a monomorphism in $\mathsf{C}$, you need to prove that $\varphi_U\circ f=\varphi_U\circ g\Rightarrow f=g$ for all arrows $\mathsf{C}$, not just those arising as components of a morphism of (pre)sheaves. So the formation of the big diagram doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've said in the comments. Do you see how we could prove it then?

Comment: Ah yes I missed your comment sorry.

Comment: But in fact the right-hand square in your larger diagram is still valid, and the commutativity of that square is sufficient to justify that $\varphi_U$ is a monomorphism.

Comment: @ArnaudD. does it? Could you tell me why?

Comment: The diagonal of the square is a mono (because it's the composition of the lower horizontal and left vertical arrows), and thus $\varphi_U$ is a mono as well.

Comment: @ArnaudD. nice! Just to confirm, the product of monomorphisms is still monic?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed monic.